# Boost log linker errors (LNK2001/LNK2019 unresolved external symbol) after upgrading to Windows 11 and rebuilding boost

Tags: visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2022

I had boost compiled & working on my Visual Studio 2022 project.  After the PC was upgraded and the OS changed to Windows 11 I attempted to re-build boost and use it with the same project.  Now I get linker errors, and it seems like I have tried every suggested fix posted online.  Somehow it seems like the lib files are not being found, even though I have confirmed the include and lib directories are included properly, and have tried rebuilding boost with many different configurations.

The boost build produces libboost_*.lib files, for example

> libboost_log_setup-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_78.lib

> libboost_log_setup-vc143-mt-x32-1_78.lib

> libboost_log-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_78.lib

> libboost_log-vc143-mt-x32-1_78.lib

Here are my boost build options

x86

> b2 -j 16 --stagedir=stage/Win32 threading=multi --toolset=msvc-14.3
> link=static runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete architecture=x86
> address-model=32

x64

> b2 -j 16 --stagedir=stage/x64 threading=multi --toolset=msvc-14.3
> link=static runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete architecture=x64
> --address-model=64

And my Visual Studio properties

C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories

> C:\Program Files\Code Libraries\boost\boost_1_78_0

Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

> C:\Program Files\Code
> Libraries\boost\boost_1_78_0\stage$(Platform)\lib

And here's an example of the errors

```
1>Logging.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned int __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const *)" (?get_id_from_string@attribute_name@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@CAIPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_name::attribute_name(char const *)" (??0attribute_name@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@QAE@PBD@Z)
1>Logging.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound *)" (?release_compound@?$stream_provider@D@aux@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@SAXPAUstream_compound@12345@@Z)
1>Logging.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void * __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned int)" (??2impl@attribute@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@SAPAXI@Z) referenced in function "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute_value __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attributes::make_attribute_value<unsigned int &>(unsigned int &)" (??$make_attribute_value@AAI@attributes@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_value@123@AAI@Z)
1>Logging.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3impl@attribute@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@SAXPAXI@Z) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??$make_attribute_value@AAI@attributes@v2s_mt_nt62@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_value@123@AAI@Z$0
```

Edit: I also wanted to mention my preprocessor variables for Debug/Win32

> WIN32
> _DEBUG
> _CONSOLE WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
> _WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00

I haven't been able to find a _WIN32_WINNT value for Windows 11, and I thought maybe that could be the problem.  But I'm not entirely sure that matters.

Comment: *"I haven't been able to find a _WIN32_WINNT value for Windows 11"* - Roughly two years after this question was posted, I still haven't been able to find one either! Did you eventually find a value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Boost, and Boost.Log in particular, was built for a different Windows version. You need to either:

- Build Boost with `_WIN32_WINNT` defined to the same version as you define when you build your code.
- Define `BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION` when building your code to the Windows version Boost should target, which would be lower than your `_WIN32_WINNT`. Also define `_WIN32_WINNT` or `BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION` macro to that version when building Boost.

To define the macro when building Boost add [`define=macro=value`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties) to the `b2` command line. For example, `define=_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00`.

Comment: It built fine for x86/32-bit, but I get this error when trying to build for 64-bit
"error: "x64" is not a known value of feature <architecture>"
"error: legal values: "x86" "ia64" "sparc" "power" "mips" "mips1" "mips2" "mips3" "mips4" "mips32" "mips32r2" "mips64" "parisc" "arm" "riscv" "s390x""

Comment: I can confirm that your answer did allow me to build and run my code targeting x86/32-bit platforms.  I cannot build for x64 still however, due to my previous comment.

Comment: If you're trying to build 64-bit Boost binaries then the option you're looking for is [`address-model=64`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties) (note no leading dashes). `architecture` property is `x86` regardless of bitness.

Comment: Oh I was confused on the architecture property I guess.  I thought the architecture property should match the target platform that I was attempting to build for on Visual Studio.  The following build worked for 64-bit: b2 -j 16 --stagedir=stage/x64 threading=multi --toolset=msvc-14.3 link=static runtime-link=shared --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 define=_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00